# Can we consider the nextPageToken ( Yotube API v3 ) a permanent ID for certain constant set of results?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-apis-explorer

Since I have been working with `search API` `Youtube API v3`, I am having a daily query limit of ~ 100. What I wanted to do is to fetch particular youtube channel's latest videos(if any).

If my quota gets full, I am considering the `nextPageToken` as my id to resume my call the next day and fetch the latest videos (if any).

Can I consider this id as a permanent ID (as I will be storing it as a reference)?
Can I consider that the page tokens are according to the timeline?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into using etags, since they should only change when there is different(new) returned data. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#etags

> **Caching and conditional retrieval** – Your application can cache API resources and their ETags. Then, when your application requests a stored resource again, it specifies the ETag associated with that resource. If the resource has changed, the API returns the modified resource and the ETag associated with that version of the resource. If the resource has not changed, the API returns an HTTP 304 response (`Not Modified`), which indicates that the resource has not changed. Your application can reduce latency and bandwidth usage by serving cached resources in this manner.